# Customize error message using Kotlin's use instead of try catch

Tags: kotlin, exception, try-catch

I'm still learning Kotlin and I just learned about the "use" and how it is a replacement for a try, catch and finally block.
However I am curious if it is possible to customize it's exception handling for example:

```
var connection: Connection? = null
try {
    connection = dataSource.connection
    connection.prepareStatement(query).execute()
} catch (e: SQLException) {
    logger.log("Specific error for that query")
    e.printStackTrace()
} finally {
    if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed) {
        connection.close()
    }
}
```

That code is my current one, I have a specific error I would like to display on the catch, would that be possible using `use`?
This is my current use code:

```
dataSource.connection.use { connection ->
    connection.prepareStatement(query).execute()
}
```

Comment: `use` only replaces `finally`. You still need `try`/`catch` inside the `use` block if you want to catch something.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Oh yeah that would make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by @Tenfour04, and from the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/use.html)

> [`use`] Executes the given block function on this resource and then closes it down correctly whether an exception is thrown or not.

In particular it is [implemented](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.3.71/libraries/stdlib/jdk7/src/kotlin/AutoCloseable.kt) like this:

```
public inline fun <T : AutoCloseable?, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R {
    var exception: Throwable? = null
    try {
        return block(this)
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        exception = e
        throw e
    } finally {
        this.closeFinally(exception)
    }
}
```

That piece of code should look familiar if you're a Java developer, but basically it executes `block` passing `this` (i.e. the receiver object) as an argument to your block of code. At the end it closes the `AutoCloseable` resource. If at any point an exception is thrown (either inside `block` or while closing the resource), that exception is thrown back to the caller, i.e. your code.

As an edge case you could have 2 exceptions, one when executing `block` and one when closing the resource. This is handled by `closeFinally` (whose source is available in the same file linked above) and the exception thrown while closing the resource is added as a suppressed exception to the one thrown from `block` – that's because only up to 1 exception can be thrown by a method, so they had to choose which one to throw. The same actually applies to the try-with-resources statement in Java.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!